# Is this lichen or some other fungus on my palm tree?

Tags: trees, tree-care, fungus, palm, moss

I was pulling weeds and noticed the trunk of this palm tree in my backyard has a lot of moss on it. A google search described lichen but I’m not sure it looks the same as what the images of lichen on a palm tree trunk were showing. Can anyone confirm if this in fact lichen or a more harmful moss on my palm tree? I’m not sure what kind of palm tree this is either if anyone knows. I’m in north Florida.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I looks like mostly moss with small bits of light green lichen. I doubt either will harm the tree.

Comment: Also, there are many different kinds of lichens, and also mosses